# How can I link to a view in a separate application?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a view containing some tiles. I want to click one and have it take me to a separate application I have written.

Normally I would point it to my view folder to specify a view I wanted to change to. However trying something similar does not seem to work for a view that lives in a separate application folder.

I am also using routing in a component, how can I do this?

I can use

```
window.location.href = 'http://...';
```

but is there a better way to do it that works alongside the router?

Comment: Are the other views still deployed within the same application?

Comment: This question may not be relevant to me after all, but the correct answer would still be of great interest for the future. The views of other apps are indeed deployed within the same overall application. I can link them using ../name_of_app and this works, but I think to do it properly I'd need to rewrite the sections to do with routing.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to plug sub-apps into a main-app, it is probably best to take the component-style approach, similar to what the Fiori launchpad would do. In a typical Fiori setup, the launchpad is the main app and the app that you would like to navigate to is setup as a component.

More information here:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/958ead51e2e94ab8bcdc90fb7e9d53d0.html

There's a separate chapter on routing in components here:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/acdb6cd408ec4b9eb5e1fe45e607abdd.html